# how to access a shared folder in another machine using C language

Tags: c, shared-directory

I'm new in C/C++ and I need to retrieve images from a shared folder place in another computer for processing. How can I do that? Can someone please provide me some guidance or sample codes on how to do it? Besides, can I also get the list of files in a folder in the shared folder?

Comment: Shared how? HTTP? WebDAV? CIFS? SMB? NFS? FTP? TFTP? SFTP? Rsync? DLNA? BitTorrent?

Comment: er... the shared folder is in another computer which is connected through network. Can I just access the file directly and do something with the image without copying the images to the local computer? is not htpp nor webdav. this app is a window based apps which needs to obtain images from another computer for processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a file for reading:

```
char* filename = "//machine/shared/image.jpg";
FILE* f = fopen(filename, "r");
```

Read a directory:

```
struct dirent* ent;
char* path = "//machine/shared";

DIR* d = opendir(path);
while((ent = readdir(d)) != NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n", ent->d_name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on Windows, you can use a [UNC path](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/windowsnetworking/g/unc-name.htm) to refer to the file and use normal C/C++ IO (fopen or fstream). Just be sure to escape it correctly as part of the C string.

Comment: ok. Is the any sample code which i can refer to for this solution?